# Is it possible to disable home button temporarily for other apps on rooted device?

Tags: android, homescreen, android-launcher, disabled-input, android-homebutton

Is it possible to disable home button temporarily for other apps on a rooted device?

I am making a program that controls other programs. I have full root access.
Is there a way I can disable the home button so that other apps can't use it if they
aren't allowed? Implementing a home screen doesn't work because I want to disable
the button for other programs as well.

I suppose maybe I could just restart the program
that pressed home to get back again but that is kind of an ugly solution.

I found this:
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-hacks-help/23552-disable-search-button.html

It works, but I would prefer not to save to a file all the time (flash wearing). Also it seems to only be working on bootup. Or is there a way to reload the configuration?

Comment: It must be available using [RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

Make a home screen activity that intercept your HOME press and then just call finish() in onCreate(). This code can launch another "launcher" at will, or do nothing as you please.